# Bug Running Android Tutorial HelloTabWidget under SDK 1.5: "setCurrentTag(getIntent())"

Tags: java, android

does not compile. Indeed: even in 1.5, this api, getIntent(), is already listed as deprecated.

The error message I get complains that getIntent() does not return a String, but setCurrentTab() expects a string.

If I guess and change the line to read:

"tabHost.setCurrentTab(1); // was setCurrentTab(getIntent())",

then it compiles, builds, but does not run. I get the "stopped unexpectedly" error message from the emulator. I cannot even get Log.d to output, so it seems that it stops 'unexpectedly' very early.

So the first and main question is: what is the correct fix to "tabHost.setCurrentTab(getIntent())" in the final line of OnCreate() in http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html?

The second and simpler question is: did I guess right in replacing 'mTabHost' with tabHost in the one place where that occurs?

Comment: Do you mean `setCurrentTabByTag` or `setCurrentTag`? The former expects a `String` and the latter expects an `int`.

Comment: To people who stumble across this post without knowing how Stack Overflow works: This site doesn't work like a typical forum. It's a question and answer site and replies to the question are meant to be solutions to his problem, not "thank you" messages. (I know, normally being polite is a good thing :P  But leaving those replies just clutters up the post, and makes it more difficult to find the actual solutions.)

Answer (score 4):

Here's the problems and fixes for that particular tutorial:

**Step 2:**  When creating your activities, if you do not create them through the manifest then you'll need to add them to the manifest manually.

Add these lines to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
  <activity android:name=".AlbumsActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        </activity>
  <activity android:name=".ArtistsActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        </activity>
          <activity android:name=".SongsActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        </activity>
```

**Step 3:**  You are only instructed to create the ic_tab_artists.xml file.  You'll need to create one for ic_tab_songs.xml and ic_tab_albums.xml as well.   You can just duplicate the ic_tab_artists.xml (or change the HelloTabView.java tab specs to use the artists.xml file for each tab).

**Step 4:** The third to last line under /res/layout/main has a typo (a ; instead of a :)

```
      android:padding="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

**Step 6:** There is a typo that uses calls mTabHost instead of tabHost.  Change it.

As already cited the getIntent() function on the last line isn't appropriate.   I just call the tab based on it's id.  eg:

```
 tabHost.setCurrentTabByTag("albums");
```

Comment: I know this is an old question, but as I am just getting into Android development, this answered my question perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

At the Informal Android Meetup, I was able to confirm that my first guess was in the ballpark: the line as printed in the tutorial really is wrong, it should be replaced with something like, "tabHost.setCurrentTab(0); // was setCurrentTab(getIntent())".

There was one other major omission I had to fix before I could get the HelloTabWidget Tutorial to run: Albums|Artists|SongsActivity all had to be added to the manifest, manifest.xml. Somehow, the tutorial instructions managed to omit mention of this requirement.

Comment: and so, you should include them here (as then they would be helpful to others)

Comment: Actually, they will learn better if they type the correction themselves, figuring out how based on my description. Such learning, after all, is the real purpose of the tutorial.